# How to make window close on clicking "exit" MenuItem()?

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem, jmenubar

```
public class Manubar extends JFrame {

    JMenuBar jmb;
    JMenu jm;
    JMenu jm2;
    JMenuItem jmt;
    JMenuItem jmt2;

    public Manubar() {
        setSize(500, 500);

        jmb = new JMenuBar();
        jm = new JMenu("file");
        jm2 = new JMenu("edit");
        jmt = new JMenuItem("copy");
        jmt2 = new JMenuItem("exit");
        jmb.add(jm);
        jmb.add(jm2);
        jm.add(jmt);
        jm.add(jmt2);
        add(jmb, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Manubar();
    }
}
```

Here I want to close the window when I click on exit menu item, 
also before closing, it should display a popup to ask whether to close if user clicks OK then it should close.

Comment: What you have tried to do so??

Comment: i am new to swings was using actionListener on exit menuitem but i am confused how to use JOptionPane to popup and when i click ok the frame should close

Comment: Add an actionlistner and on onclick show a joptionpane and on bases of its value exit from the frame. Try it then what problem you are facing share it. Then we will help you.

Comment: 1) It is Swing, not Swings. 2) Go through [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html). 3) Please be more specific in future about what you've tried, and where you are stuck. SO is a Q&A site, not a help desk & not a place to find a tutor..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Here I want to close the window when I click on exit menu item, also before closing, it should display a popup to ask whether to close if user clicks OK then it should close.

Check out [Closing an Application](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/). It shows you how to display a JOptionPane to confirm closing of the application first.

It shows:

1. the basic approach of using a WindowListener
2. a simplified approach by using the included custom classes

Answer (score 3):

Here is your complete solution,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Manubar extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JMenuBar jmb;
    JMenu jm;
    JMenu jm2;
    JMenuItem jmt;
    JMenuItem jmt2;

    public Manubar() {
        setSize(500, 500);

        jmb = new JMenuBar();
        jm = new JMenu("file");
        jm2 = new JMenu("edit");
        jmt = new JMenuItem("copy");
        jmt2 = new JMenuItem("exit");
        jmb.add(jm);
        jmb.add(jm2);
        jm.add(jmt);
        jm.add(jmt2);
        add(jmb, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jmt2.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Manubar();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

       if("exit".equals(e.getActionCommand())){

         int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
         JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Would You Like to Save your Previous Note First?","Warning",dialogButton);

         if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            System.exit(NORMAL);
         }

    }

    }

}
```

Comment: @darknight, `Here is your complete solution,` - it doesn't show how to display the popup.